# Tensorflow gpu training fails with OOM when the exact code runs on an older computer with no issues

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently got a new laptop with an inbuilt graphics card from Intel and one extra from Nvidia.
I installed cuda and drivers of this version
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.39.01    Driver Version: 510.39.01    CUDA Version: 11.6

I also have Tensorflow 2.7.
I am trying to run a network that was working perfectly on my old computer, more or less being taken from this repository:

https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet.git

but I get the following warning when i initiate the model:

```
2022-02-02 14:47:03.039319: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
```

and when i actually try to train the model it runs OOM without training at all. (Error message simplified for character limit)

```
2022-02-02 14:50:00.390958: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.02GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-02-02 14:50:00.391000: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.02GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-02-02 14:50:02.218748: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] 
2022-02-02 14:50:12.687857: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 7f16daade200 of size 524288 next 155
2022-02-02 14:50:12.687865: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 7f16dab5e200 of size 1179648 next 157
2022-02-02 14:50:12.688670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1078] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 5.17GiB
2022-02-02 14:50:12.688678: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1080] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 6427901952 memory_limit_: 6427901952 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 12855803904
2022-02-02 14:50:12.688695: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1086] Stats: 
Limit:                      6427901952
InUse:                      5546784512
MaxInUse:                   6126439680
NumAllocs:                         645
MaxAllocSize:               3716153344
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2022-02-02 14:50:12.688718: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:474] **********************************************************_____******************************_______
2022-02-02 14:50:12.688819: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_input_ops.cc:335 : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,128,1024,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <module>
----> 1 model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=10,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:2016, in Model.fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2005 """Fits the model on data yielded batch-by-batch by a Python generator.
   2006 
   2007 DEPRECATED:
   2008   `Model.fit` now supports generators, so there is no longer any need to use
   2009   this endpoint.
   2010 """
   2011 warnings.warn(
   2012     '`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
   2013     'will be removed in a future version. '
   2014     'Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.',
   2015     stacklevel=2)
-> 2016 return self.fit(
   2017     generator,
   2018     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   2019     epochs=epochs,
   2020     verbose=verbose,
   2021     callbacks=callbacks,
   2022     validation_data=validation_data,
   2023     validation_steps=validation_steps,
   2024     validation_freq=validation_freq,
   2025     class_weight=class_weight,
   2026     max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
   2027     workers=workers,
   2028     use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   2029     shuffle=shuffle,
   2030     initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:58, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     56 try:
     57   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 58   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     59                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     61   if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,128,1024,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[node gradient_tape/model/conv2d_20/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput
 (defined at /home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:464)
]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_3020]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node gradient_tape/model/conv2d_20/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput:
In[0] gradient_tape/model/conv2d_20/Conv2D/ShapeN:      
In[1] model/conv2d_20/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp (defined at /home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py:224)      
In[2] gradient_tape/model/conv2d_20/ReluGrad:

Operation defined at: (most recent call last)
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
>>>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
>>>     exec(code, run_globals)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
>>>     app.launch_new_instance()
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
>>>     app.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
>>>     self.io_loop.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 199, in start
>>>     self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
>>>     self._run_once()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
>>>     handle._run()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
>>>     self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
>>>     await self.process_one()
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
>>>     await dispatch(*args)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 357, in dispatch_shell
>>>     await result
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 652, in execute_request
>>>     reply_content = await reply_content
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 353, in do_execute
>>>     res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
>>>     return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2768, in run_cell
>>>     result = self._run_cell(
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2814, in _run_cell
>>>     return runner(coro)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
>>>     coro.send(None)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3012, in run_cell_async
>>>     has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3191, in run_ast_nodes
>>>     if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3251, in run_code
>>>     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>>> 
>>>   File "/tmp/ipykernel_20858/1898079364.py", line 1, in <module>
>>>     model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=10,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2016, in fit_generator
>>>     return self.fit(
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1216, in fit
>>>     tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function
>>>     return step_function(self, iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function
>>>     outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step
>>>     outputs = model.train_step(data)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 816, in train_step
>>>     self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 530, in minimize
>>>     grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 583, in _compute_gradients
>>>     grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
>>> 
>>>   File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 464, in _get_gradients
>>>     grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
>>>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could have caused this/how to resolve it?
best

Comment: Just because the hardware is newer, doesn't mean it can't run out of memory. What model is your current GPU? What GPU did your previous computer have? Are there other processed that might be eating your GPU memory?

Comment: Sadly not, i have killed everything save python. Current gpu has slightly more memory. Potentially the drivers are taking more. THanks, that might be it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a hard limit on the total GPU memory as shown in this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth) and let us know if it works.

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

also check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36025#issuecomment-628145158)

Comment: sadly, i tried all those and nothing seems to work.